# how to see if a rgb color is too light

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, colors, rgb

I have an aplication in which the customer chooses a color.
I can't let this color be too light.
Is there a way to see this, to prevent the customer from chosing a color that is too light?

Thank you a lot!

---

too light in the case is a color almost white....i have a web site with a white background and the user can choose a color through a jquery plugin.

I want to allow the user to choose the color he wants, but cant be too light.

Comment: Are you using a plugin for color selection? This is the kind of important information you need to include in questions.

Comment: What about converting the color from RGB to HSV (hue, saturation, value) and checking the S and V values? That's just a shot in the dark, but that'd be the first thing I'd try

Comment: do you have a definition for "too light"?

Comment: too light is a color almost white....I am using a jquery plugin to pick the rgb color

Comment: So you need contrast to white.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If contrast is what you are looking for then [check out this article](http://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast).

They show a function like this to choose text color based on any arbitrary color:

```
function isTooLightYIQ(hexcolor){
  var r = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(0,2),16);
  var g = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(2,2),16);
  var b = parseInt(hexcolor.substr(4,2),16);
  var yiq = ((r*299)+(g*587)+(b*114))/1000;
  return yiq >= 128;
}

// usage:
element.style.color = isTooLightYIQ('ff0045') ? '#000' : '#fff';
```

The above function will return true if the color is too light for white text to be readable on top of this color.

Answer (score 0):

'too light' relative to what? Some image? pure white? some shade of grey? Easiest method is to just make sure that one of the R,G,B member values is above some threshold, though that won't help if the user selects (128,0,0) and it's being pasted onto an image that's (127,0,0) - the difference is (1,0,0) and would be invisible or at minimum almost impossible to spot on most monitors.

Answer (score -1):

You're not being too specific, but assuming you are using Javascript,

`var v = Math.round((r+g+b)/3)` and check that it is below a certain threshold?

Also, what form is the color in? RGB? HSL? Hex?